# How to group subviews for automation?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am currently automating my iOS app. What I am currently facing is the problem to group my subviews in order to separate them from the others. Ok, to be clear, here is what I have:

- Custom view container - MyContainerView1
- -MyUIImageView
- -MyUITextField
- -MyUIButton
- Custom view container - MyContainerView2
- -MyUIImageView
- -MyUITextField
- -MyUIButton

Ok, during the automation process I want to be able to access all the subviews(this includes MyUIImageView, MyUITextField, MyUIButton). To do so, I have to set them all to UIAccessibilityEnabled = YES, set labels and set all MyContainerView instances' UIAccessibilityEnabled = NO.

Ok, but when I log the elements tree, the subviews are not grouped(because MyContainerView's accessibility is disabled, so I can't get the group:

- -MyUIImageView
- -MyUITextField
- -MyUIButton

and work with it as a whole object(get it's imageView, it's textField, check their properties, etc.).

Instead, I get this:

- -MyUIImageView
- -MyUITextField
- -MyUIButton
- -MyUIImageView
- -MyUITextField
- -MyUIButton

This way I don't know which MyUIImageView belongs to which MyContainerView, so I can't group them.

So, my question is how can I group them in order to automate them?

Comment: put them in an `NSArray`?

Comment: This is what I did - it is a very error prone suggestion. The reason - if just one view appears of nowhere(it's added later, or whateever), you're screwed. I am looking for a better suggestion :)

Comment: BTW, I guess you meant Array(), because I am talking about UIAutomation and Javascript. Or?

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly not setting the container view's accessibility properties because that will mess up the elements inside it.

Why do you need the grouping? If you use `window.elements().withName('MyUIButton')` you get an array with all elements that are named MyUiButton. So `window.elements().withName('MyUIButton')[0]` will be the one from the first view, and `window.elements().withName('MyUIButton')[1]` will be the one from the second.

Maybe not as nice as grouping, but this is really inside tests, not inside real code.
If you really need some groupingish solution, you can alter the accessibility properties of the elements runtime, to add a prefix for all subelements of the views. Something like view1_MyUiButton and view2_MyUiButton.

Comment: Grouping is needed because MyUIButton and MyUIImageView are as one whole view. I don't want them to be separated, neither I want to get MyUIButton[i] and MyUIImageView[i](for obvious error prone reasons). The prefixing is a very hackish way, I don't like it. Perhaps I should consider it... Anyway, are you aware of other uiautomation frameworks that support such functionality?